# Common root of cubic and quadratic equation

Tags: roots, quadratics, cubics, common-root

> If equations $ax^3+2bx^2+3cx+4d=0$ and $ax^2+bx+c=0$ have a non zero common root, prove that $(c^2-2bd)(b^2-ac) \geq 0$.

I know the condition of common root of two quadratic equations but I have no idea on how to proceed with this question.

Comment: This has a more complete answer [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42822/given-a-cubic-and-quadratic-share-a-root-prove-ac-b2bd-c2-geq-0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can multiply the second by $x$ and subtract from the first.  That leaves $(2b-a)x^2+(3c-b)x+(4d-c)=0$ and $ax^2+bx+c=0$ as two quadratic equations, which you know how to handle.

Comment: how can subtraction give common roots? Any logic behind there. I came accross people subtract Biquadratic and cubic for common root l... but why?